# Using GeoServer GetFeatureInfo template?

Tags: geoserver, getfeatureinfo, template

My question consists of a few points, as I just read the GeoServer GetFeatureInfo template tutorials and it is very effective and useful for my project.

My questions are:

- Where is the data directory of GeoServer where the templates resides?
- How to call layers and apply styling?

Comment: please try to limit yourself to one question per question, taking the [tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) may help you to understand how this site works.

Answer (score 2):

GeoServer looks in a [list of places for templates](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/freemarker.html#template-lookup):

- Look into
  `GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR/workspaces/<workspace>/<datastore>/<featuretype>/content.ftl`
  to see if there is a feature type specific template
- Look into `GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR/workspaces/<workspace>/<datastore>/content.ftl` to
  see if there is a store specific template
- Look into `GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR/workspaces/<workspace>/content.ftl` to see if there is a workspace specific template
- Look into `GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR/workspaces/content.ftl` looking for a global override
- Look into `GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR/templates/content.ftl` looking for a global override
- Look into the GeoServer classpath and load the default template

Comment: And how can those by accessed from my localchost?

Comment: go to your geoserver data directory (GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR) and look in the directories above

Comment: Thank you so much. I was searching it in the program files etc but  found it in the Program data/Geoserver etc Folder.

Comment: Hello, could you please tell me where I can find the default `content.ftl`(if that is the name) to take a look at the code, in GeoServer 2.8. I have looked in `C:\ProgramData\Boundless\OpenGeo\geoserver\workspaces\<ws_name>` and there is nothing close to `content.ftl`. I have not set a `GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR` var myself and I read that `C:\ProgramData\Boundless\OpenGeo\geoserver\data_dir` would be the default but inside all I found was `filter.properties`, `GeoLiteCity.dat` and `monitor.properties`. every manual or forum tells me what you answered but there is nothing there, please help

Comment: found it here: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Boundless\OpenGeo\jetty\webapps\geoserver\WEB-INF\lib\gs-wms-2.8-SNAPSHOT.jar`. inside a `.jar` file! what do you know. 

this helped: **Missing the source for the default template, look up for the service jar in the geoserver distribution (for example, wms-x.y.z.jar), unpack it, and you’ll find the actual xxx.ftl files
GeoServer is using as the default templates.** I found it the GeoServer 2.8.0 user manual, p.1015. 

thanx anyway

Comment: so what I said - Look into the GeoServer classpath and load the default template

Comment: don;t forget to upvote the answer if it helped you